# Counting principles and probability question

Tags: probability

A batch of 15 DVD players contains 4 that are defective. The DVD players are selected at random, one by one, and examined. The ones that are checked are not replaced.

a. What is the probability that there are exactly 3 defective DVD players in the first 8 DVD players examined?

b. What is the probability that the 9th DVD player examined is the 4th defective one found?

I have the mark scheme, but I'm still a bit confused.

[image]

I kind of understand part a, but I don't really understand part b, especially where they go the 1/7 from. If someone could explain this all to me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The $\frac17$ in part b) comes from the fact that we are looking at the situation where $8$ DVD players, of which $3$ are defective have already been selected.  So of the $7$ remaining players, $1$ is defective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to part $(b)$:

If we are know that from the first 8 DVD players 3 are defective, then there are only one defective player left from the remaining 7. Therefore, probability that 9th selected DVD player is defective from remaining 7 is $\frac{1}{7}$. So,

$$
P(9th \space selected \space is \space 4th \space defective \space \cap \space 3 \space defective \space in \space first \space 8)=P(9th \space selected \space is \space 4th \space defective )=P(3 \space defective \space in \space first \space 8).P(9th \space selected \space is \space 4th \space defective \space |\space 3 \space defective \space in \space first \space 8)=\frac{56}{195}.\frac{1}{7}=\frac{8}{195}
$$